# When Inserting a table in a report all records get populated but the same data in a text box does not populate all records?

Tags: c#, sql, reportviewer

I am designing a report, first off this report is generated through GUI idk if that is going to make any difference, i designed a new report through the wizard than attached that report to the report viewer, ended up with this code:

```
 private void PrintAllBag_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'corsicanaNetWeightDataSet11.Net_Weight_Master_Data_Report1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.Net_Weight_Master_Data_Report1TableAdapter.Fill(this.corsicanaNetWeightDataSet11.Net_Weight_Master_Data_Report1);

            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

        }
```

The Query i used to populate the dataset is:

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT [Net Weight Master Data].[Unit UPC Base Item], [Net Weight Master Data].[Production Line], [Production Lines].[Production Line Description], 
                         [Net Weight Master Data].[Preset Number], [Net Weight Master Data].[Weight Factor], [Net Weight Master Data].Piece, [Net Weight Master Data].[Pcs Per Unit], 
                         [Net Weight Master Data].[Upper Limit Unit], [Net Weight Master Data].[Upper Limit Factor], [Net Weight Master Data].[Label Wt (g)], 
                         [Net Weight Master Data].[Tare Wt (g)], [Net Weight Master Data].[Constant Tare Wt (g)], [Net Weight Master Data].[Pkg Length (mm)], 
                         [Net Weight Master Data].[Film Product Code], [Net Weight Master Data].[Film Width (mm)], [Net Weight Master Data].[Forming Tube (mm)], 
                         [Net Weight Master Data].[Type of Jaws], [Net Weight Master Data].[Last Updated], [Maximum Allowable Variations].[MAV (g)], 
                         CASE WHEN [Upper Limit Unit] != 'g' THEN ([Label Wt (g)] / [Pcs Per Unit]) END AS [PieceWeight(g)], 
                         ([Maximum Allowable Variations].[MAV (g)] - [Production Lines].[Scale Deviation Factor] - [Net Weight Master Data].[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF ([Net Weight Master Data].[Weight Factor], 0) AS UL1, 
                         ([Maximum Allowable Variations].[MAV (g)] - [Production Lines].[Scale Deviation Factor] - [Net Weight Master Data].[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF ([Net Weight Master Data].[Weight Factor], 0) 
                         - CAST(([Maximum Allowable Variations].[MAV (g)] - [Production Lines].[Scale Deviation Factor] - [Net Weight Master Data].[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF ([Net Weight Master Data].[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int) AS UL2, CASE WHEN [Package Type] IS NOT NULL 
                         THEN ([mav (g)] - [scale deviation factor] - [tare variation factor (g)]) / NULLIF ([weight factor], 0) 
                         WHEN (dbo.[Maximum Allowable Variations].[MAV (g)] - dbo.[Production Lines].[Scale Deviation Factor] - dbo.[Net Weight Master Data].[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF (dbo.[Net Weight Master Data].[Weight Factor], 0) 
                         - CAST((dbo.[Maximum Allowable Variations].[MAV (g)] - dbo.[Production Lines].[Scale Deviation Factor] - dbo.[Net Weight Master Data].[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF (dbo.[Net Weight Master Data].[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int) 
                         = 0 THEN CAST((dbo.[Maximum Allowable Variations].[MAV (g)] - dbo.[Production Lines].[Scale Deviation Factor] - dbo.[Net Weight Master Data].[Tare Variation Factor (g)])
                          / NULLIF (dbo.[Net Weight Master Data].[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int) 
                         WHEN (dbo.[Maximum Allowable Variations].[MAV (g)] - dbo.[Production Lines].[Scale Deviation Factor] - dbo.[Net Weight Master Data].[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF (dbo.[Net Weight Master Data].[Weight Factor], 0) 
                         - CAST((dbo.[Maximum Allowable Variations].[MAV (g)] - dbo.[Production Lines].[Scale Deviation Factor] - dbo.[Net Weight Master Data].[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF (dbo.[Net Weight Master Data].[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int) > 0 AND 
                         (dbo.[Maximum Allowable Variations].[MAV (g)] - dbo.[Production Lines].[Scale Deviation Factor] - dbo.[Net Weight Master Data].[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF (dbo.[Net Weight Master Data].[Weight Factor], 0) 
                         - CAST((dbo.[Maximum Allowable Variations].[MAV (g)] - dbo.[Production Lines].[Scale Deviation Factor] - dbo.[Net Weight Master Data].[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF (dbo.[Net Weight Master Data].[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int) 
                         < 0.51 THEN CAST((dbo.[Maximum Allowable Variations].[MAV (g)] - dbo.[Production Lines].[Scale Deviation Factor] - dbo.[Net Weight Master Data].[Tare Variation Factor (g)])
                          / NULLIF (dbo.[Net Weight Master Data].[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int) 
                         + [Rounding Factor1] ELSE CAST((dbo.[Maximum Allowable Variations].[MAV (g)] - dbo.[Production Lines].[Scale Deviation Factor] - dbo.[Net Weight Master Data].[Tare Variation Factor (g)])
                          / NULLIF (dbo.[Net Weight Master Data].[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int) + [Rounding Factor2] END AS UL3, 
                         CASE WHEN [package type] = 'Bar' THEN 10 WHEN [upper limit unit] != 'g' THEN ([label wt (g)] / [pcs per unit]) * ([upper limit factor]) 
                         WHEN [upper limit unit] = 'g' THEN CASE WHEN [package type] IS NOT NULL THEN ([mav (g)] - [scale deviation factor] - [tare variation factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF ([weight factor], 0) 
                         WHEN (dbo.[maximum allowable variations].[mav (g)] - dbo.[production lines].[scale deviation factor] - dbo.[net weight master data].[tare variation factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF (dbo.[net weight master data].[weight factor], 0) 
                         - CAST((dbo.[maximum allowable variations].[mav (g)] - dbo.[production lines].[scale deviation factor] - dbo.[net weight master data].[tare variation factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF (dbo.[net weight master data].[weight factor], 0) AS INT) 
                         = 0 THEN CAST((dbo.[maximum allowable variations].[mav (g)] - dbo.[production lines].[scale deviation factor] - dbo.[net weight master data].[tare variation factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF (dbo.[net weight master data].[weight factor], 0) AS INT) 
                         WHEN (dbo.[maximum allowable variations].[mav (g)] - dbo.[production lines].[scale deviation factor] - dbo.[net weight master data].[tare variation factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF (dbo.[net weight master data].[weight factor], 0) 
                         - CAST((dbo.[maximum allowable variations].[mav (g)] - dbo.[production lines].[scale deviation factor] - dbo.[net weight master data].[tare variation factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF (dbo.[net weight master data].[weight factor], 0) AS INT) > 0 AND 
                         (dbo.[maximum allowable variations].[mav (g)] - dbo.[production lines].[scale deviation factor] - dbo.[net weight master data].[tare variation factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF (dbo.[net weight master data].[weight factor], 0) 
                         - CAST((dbo.[maximum allowable variations].[mav (g)] - dbo.[production lines].[scale deviation factor] - dbo.[net weight master data].[tare variation factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF (dbo.[net weight master data].[weight factor], 0) AS INT) 
                         < 0.51 THEN CAST((dbo.[maximum allowable variations].[mav (g)] - dbo.[production lines].[scale deviation factor] - dbo.[net weight master data].[tare variation factor (g)])
                          / NULLIF (dbo.[net weight master data].[weight factor], 0) AS INT) 
                         + [rounding factor1] ELSE CAST((dbo.[maximum allowable variations].[mav (g)] - dbo.[production lines].[scale deviation factor] - dbo.[net weight master data].[tare variation factor (g)])
                          / NULLIF (dbo.[net weight master data].[weight factor], 0) AS INT) + [rounding factor2] END * ([weight factor]) END AS [UpperLimit(g)], 
                         CASE WHEN [upper limit unit] = 'g' THEN CASE WHEN [package type] IS NOT NULL THEN ([mav (g)] - [scale deviation factor] - [tare variation factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF ([weight factor], 0) 
                         WHEN (dbo.[maximum allowable variations].[mav (g)] - dbo.[production lines].[scale deviation factor] - dbo.[net weight master data].[tare variation factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF (dbo.[net weight master data].[weight factor], 0) 
                         - CAST((dbo.[maximum allowable variations].[mav (g)] - dbo.[production lines].[scale deviation factor] - dbo.[net weight master data].[tare variation factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF (dbo.[net weight master data].[weight factor], 0) AS INT) 
                         = 0 THEN CAST((dbo.[maximum allowable variations].[mav (g)] - dbo.[production lines].[scale deviation factor] - dbo.[net weight master data].[tare variation factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF (dbo.[net weight master data].[weight factor], 0) AS INT) 
                         WHEN (dbo.[maximum allowable variations].[mav (g)] - dbo.[production lines].[scale deviation factor] - dbo.[net weight master data].[tare variation factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF (dbo.[net weight master data].[weight factor], 0) 
                         - CAST((dbo.[maximum allowable variations].[mav (g)] - dbo.[production lines].[scale deviation factor] - dbo.[net weight master data].[tare variation factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF (dbo.[net weight master data].[weight factor], 0) AS INT) > 0 AND 
                         (dbo.[maximum allowable variations].[mav (g)] - dbo.[production lines].[scale deviation factor] - dbo.[net weight master data].[tare variation factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF (dbo.[net weight master data].[weight factor], 0) 
                         - CAST((dbo.[maximum allowable variations].[mav (g)] - dbo.[production lines].[scale deviation factor] - dbo.[net weight master data].[tare variation factor (g)]) 
                         / NULLIF (dbo.[net weight master data].[weight factor], 0) AS INT) 
                         < 0.51 THEN CAST((dbo.[maximum allowable variations].[mav (g)] - dbo.[production lines].[scale deviation factor] - dbo.[net weight master data].[tare variation factor (g)])
                          / NULLIF (dbo.[net weight master data].[weight factor], 0) AS INT) 
                         + [rounding factor1] ELSE CAST((dbo.[maximum allowable variations].[mav (g)] - dbo.[production lines].[scale deviation factor] - dbo.[net weight master data].[tare variation factor (g)])
                          / NULLIF (dbo.[net weight master data].[weight factor], 0) AS INT) + [rounding factor2] END * ([weight factor]) END AS [LowerLimit(g)], 
                         CASE WHEN [Package Type] = 'Bar' THEN ([Net Weight Master Data].[Label Wt (g)]) - ([Maximum Allowable Variations].[MAV (g)]) 
                         + ([Net Weight Master Data].[Tare Wt (g)]) 
                         WHEN dbo.[Net Weight Master Data].[Package Type] = '10 Pack' THEN [Label Wt (g)] - [MAV (g)] + [tare Wt (g)] + 2.5 ELSE [Label Wt (g)] - [Maximum Allowable Variations].[MAV (g)]
                          + [tare Wt (g)] + 5 END AS [Repair Min Wt (g)], ItemDesc.[Item Description]
FROM            [Net Weight Master Data] LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         [Production Lines] ON [Net Weight Master Data].[Production Line] = [Production Lines].[Production Line] INNER JOIN
                         [Maximum Allowable Variations] ON [Net Weight Master Data].[Label Wt (g)] = [Maximum Allowable Variations].[Labeled Quantity (g)] LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         ItemDesc ON [Net Weight Master Data].[Unit UPC Base Item] = ItemDesc.[Unit UPC Base Item]
ORDER BY [Net Weight Master Data].[Unit UPC Base Item], [Net Weight Master Data].[Production Line]
```

As you can see i am doing a select all and there are no parameters involved in the dataset but still my report only displays the first record, i am not sure if this is a constraint with the reportviewer or report designer, where can i modify  so that the report displays all the records. there are a total of 2373 records, i would just love to click the navigation pain on the top and go next and next

Picture of my form plz click here [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHWHr.png)

any help is generously appreciated thnks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and i fixed the issue with some help from stackoverflow, so like you stated in your question a table in a report has a ability to repeat for all records but not textboxes, you can accomplish your task by following the following steps:

1. Make sure you have a Dataset defined for your report.
2. Add a "Table" control to the report. This seems to be needed in order to iterate the rows in your Dataset.
3. Delete the header row and two of the default columns from the table so that you are left with a single row with a single column.
4. Expand the table to the width of your layout and make it as tall as you will need for your "free form" layout.
5. By default, there is a TextBox inside the table cell. Right-click the empty table cell and choose "delete" to remove that TextBox.
6. Drag a "Rectangle" control into the empty table cell. It seems to automatically "dock" to the width/height of the table cell.
7. Now you should be able to drag the fields from your DataSet (TextBoxes, etc) into the Rectangle to produce the desired layout.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Exactly what i needed, reports for all items are generating page after page and look beautiful appreciate the help bud!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there are 2373 records in the [Net Weight Master Data] table then it is most likely the INNER JOIN in your query which is restricting the results. Try removing the INNER JOIN from your query and run it again. Without more context in your question it's hard to give a more specific answer than that.

I'd also suggest removing the TOP (100) PERCENT from you SELECT as it doesn't do anything in your query.